# Link list incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I dont understand why assigning 'root' to equal to 'trieu' would be an incompatible pointer :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct uniform {
    char size;
    int number;
    struct uniform *ext;
};

struct uniform *trieu;
struct unifrom *root;

int main(void) {
    trieu = malloc(sizeof(struct uniform));
    root = trieu;
...
    trieu = root;
```

When I compile it with gcc it gives me:

```
program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:15:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
  root = trieu;
   ^
program.c:57:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
  trieu = root;
```

It worked before in another program I made with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ll {
    char store;
    struct ll *ext;
};

struct ll *trieu;
struct ll *root;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    trieu = malloc(sizeof(struct ll));
    root = trieu;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Use `struct uniform *root;` instead of `struct unifrom *root;`.

Answer (score -2):

First of all when using malloc to allocate a new sturct you need to cast the return pointer.

```
struct uniform {
    char size;
    int number;
    struct uniform *ext;
}UNIFORM;

trieu = (UNIFORM*)malloc(sizeof(UNIFORM));
```

Comment: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: True, it is unnecessary, as void * is automatically promoted to any other pointer type.